# Giving snprintf() a too large size when output is small enough

Tags: c, printf, undefined-behavior

Does this code cause undefined behaviour? Because the buffer is only 128 byte long but i tell `snprintf()` that it is longer. However, the resulting string is shorter than 128 byte.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  char buffer[128];
  snprintf(buffer,294201,"%s","ABC");
  puts(buffer);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: As "The snprintf function is equivalent to fprintf ...", we need to look at `fprintf()`.  `fprintf()` does not write past what is needs.  I suppose the question is, may it access beyond, hmmm.  I _think_ 294201 being more than 128 is not UB, but we are on thin ice.  Good luck.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica `fprintf()` does not write a `'\0'` character to the file, `snprintf()` does write one. Maybe an implementation writes `'\0'` at the end (so there is one in case the result is too long) and then writes the data.

Comment: There is no reason any sane `snprintf` implementation would write further into the buffer than past the terminating null character. Any writing beyond the null character would be completely useless and just waste CPU cycles. But you never know. But for me the code you show is broken, even if most likely nothing bad is going to happen.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123, Yes the steam vs. buffer difference is  in the `...` .  Full spec covers more detail.

Comment: I am concerned about `snprintf()` attempting to do a `buffer + 294201` addition that is invalid. I'm leaning toward UB now.

Comment: Standard: *"The snprintf function is equivalent to fprintf, except that the output is written into an array (specified by argument s) rather than to a stream. ... , output characters beyond the n-1st are discarded rather than being written to the array, and a null character is written at the end of the characters actually written into the array. ..."* This seems to imply that only accesses are characters written and one null immediately at the end of characters. No other actions are specified. That would suggest that code is safe.

Comment: If `snprintf(buffer,294201,"%s","ABC");` is not UB, then by [induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction), `snprintf(buffer, INT_MAX,"%s","ABC");` is not UB.

Answer (score 5):

C 2018 7.21.6.5 2 says:

> The `snprintf` function is equivalent to `fprintf`, except that the output is written into an array (specified by argument `s`) rather than to a stream.  If `n` is zero, nothing is written, and `s` may be a null pointer. Otherwise, output characters beyond the `n-1`<sup>st</sup> are discarded rather than being written to the array, and a null character is written at the end of the characters actually written into the array.

Note this does not say `snprintf` is passed an array of `n` or more characters. So `snprintf` is not given any license to assume it may write to `s[n-1]` unless the `fprintf` that it is equivalent to would write `n` characters (including the terminating null character).

Looking at this another way, suppose we define an array `buffer` of 294,201 characters, fill it with data, and call `snprintf(buffer,294201,"%s","ABC");`. Would we expect nothing beyond the first four characters to change? If some other byte in the buffer changed, then this `snprintf` call would not be “equivalent to `fprintf`, except that the output is written into an array…” I would deem it a violation of this specification if it changed anything further in the buffer.

Comment: UB does not have to be just writing issue.  It could be an address calculation one.  I reviewed a sample `snprintf()` [source](https://opensource.apple.com/source/network_cmds/network_cmds-511/unbound/compat/snprintf.c.auto.html) looking for possible code doing something like  `buffer + 294201` to form a "do not write pass this pointer".  Since that addition is possible UB, that would be a problem. But source code does not do that - so perhaps speaks to implementation's good quality.  Accounting for a possible overvalued `size_t n` makes for an interesting coding restriction.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: The issue calculating the address would be the same as the one for accessing memory: The specification for `snprintf` does not specify it is passed an array of size at least `n` or of any size except that needed to write the characters the specification says `snprintf` writes. So doing the address calculation in any way that has undefined behavior according to both the C standard and the implementation would not conform to the specification of the `snprintf` routine. (The implementation could do the calculation if it pleases and it guarantees no adverse effects.)